# In LinqToEntities, How to pass dynamic column name to DbFunctions.Like

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities, iqueryable, linq-expressions

I have an `IQueryable<T>` from my `DbSet` in Entity Framework.  I am provided a "Fuzzy Search String", named `searchText`, like so:

```
public List<T> Search<T>(string searchText)
{
    using (var context = ...)
    {
        var baseQuery = context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
        baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(x =>
            DbFunctions.Like(x.PropertyName, searchText)
            || DbFunctions.Like(x.PropertyTwo, searchText)
            || DbFunctions.Like(x.PropertyThree, searchText)
            || DbFunctio..... etc
        );
        return baseQuery.ToList();
    }
}
```

But given the generic nature, I don't know what properties there are on the type.  I can provide an abstract method to somebody implementing this which allows them to give me a List of Properties (or even `PropertyInfo` or whatever else, I can figure that out).  But I don't know how to dynamically create the expression.  This is what I have so far:

```
var baseQuery = context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
var expression = baseQuery.Expression;
var colName = "colName"; // Or names, I can iterate.

var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
var selector = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, colName);
expression = Expression.Call(typeof(DbFunctions), nameof(DbFunctions.Like),
    new Type[] { baseQuery.ElementType, selector.Type },
    expression, Expression.Quote(Expression.Lambda(selector, parameter)));
```

The problem here is... well, it doesn't work to begin with.  But mainly that I'm not using the `searchText` anywhere in it, and don't know how to plug it in.  I THINK I'm close... but have spent an inordinate amount of time on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully I'm getting your query logic right: if you want to build a set of `LIKE` conditions based on known type and list of column names, you could try something like this:

```
static private MethodInfo dbLikeMethod = typeof(DbFunctions).GetMethod(nameof(DbFunctions.Like), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, new Type[] {typeof(string), typeof(string)}, null); // I am targeting DbFunctions.Like(string, string). You might want another overload (or even mix them up depending on your inputs)

public List<T> Search<T>(string searchText) where T: class
{

    using (var context = new ...)
    {
        var baseQuery = context.Set<T>().AsQueryable().Where(CreateExpression<T>(searchText));// you could probably find a more elegant way of plugging it into your query
        return baseQuery.ToList();
    }
}

Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateExpression<T>(string searchText) where T : class
{   
    var cols = new List<string> {
        "PropertyName",
        "PropertyTwo" // i understand you've got a way to figure out which strings you need here
    };

    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");   
    var dbLikeCalls = cols.Select(colName => Expression.Call(dbLikeMethod, Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, colName), Expression.Constant(searchText))); // for convenience, generate list of DbFunctions.Like(x.<Property>, searchText) expressions here
    var aggregatedCalls = dbLikeCalls.Skip(1).Aggregate((Expression)dbLikeCalls.First(), (accumulate, call) => Expression.OrElse(accumulate, call)); // aggregate the list using || operators: use first item as a seed and keep adding onto it

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(aggregatedCalls, parameter);
}
```